# ThreeJS geometry vertices not updated after changing position

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am using a function to drag geometry and it works,the position values are changed. The problem is that the vertices inside geometry are not updated. How can I do to update them?

Comment: Do you mean you can move mesh by changing position or do you update geometry vertices?

Comment: I move geometry changing its positions, but the vertices coordinates of this geometry don't change. @uhura